# How to load images from SDCard into Image Switcher?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

Does anyone has the example of loading images from the sdcard to Image Switcher? 
I'm a beginner of android here. Willing to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) from the SDK docs to get familiar with data storage in Android.

Check out [this post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/443531/Android/Mobile/display-Images-stored-sdcard) on displaying images from the sd card. Also see the [ImageSwitcher API Demo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ImageSwitcher1.html). <-- Hint: Observe the ImageAdapter in the reply by "beta jane" (**EDIT**:beta jane has a better code snippet)